# Which characters require escaping in expect strings?

Tags: linux, unix, expect

I know that hard brackets `[`, `]` require triple backslash escaping when used inside `expect "..."` strings, so I use `expect "blah blah \\\[herp derp\\\]"` to accurately convey these characters to the `expect` I/O checker, but what other characters also require escaping? Pipe? Parentheses? ???

Comment: `expect` uses Tcl for it's scripts, so I would guess the same characters need escaping as in regular Tcl.

Answer (score 6):

There's 2 things going on here:

1. Tcl uses `[...]` as the "command substitution" syntax (See https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm rule 7). It's like backticks in a shell script. Within double quotes, command substitutions are performed.
2. The default pattern matching for the `expect` command is "glob" patterns. Glob patterns are documented here: 
   https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/string.htm#M35
   Square brackets are special for glob patterns.

So, first you need to protect the square brackets within double quotes to prevent command substitutions. Then, if you want to treat them as literal characters, you need to escape them again.

Here are a couple of things you can to do reduce the backslashes:

1. use non-interpolating quotes: in Tcl that is `{braces}` not `"quotes"`.
2. choose a different pattern type: if this is a literal string you want to match, use the `-ex` option to say you want an "exact" match.

Thus, you want this:

```
expect -ex {blah blah [herp derp]}
```